# How can i subtract a column vector from each column of a given matrix in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I thought about generating a blank matrix and then updating each element using a double loop, but it returns the blank matrix once again.
Here is my code: (dataset.df is the initial matrix, riskfree.df is the column i want to subtract, asset.names is simply a list of length 25 and dataset_corretto.df is the name of the new matrix i want to create)

```
**dataset_corretto.df = matrix(0, 618, 25)                                                  
for (j in dataset.df) {
  for (i in asset.names){
    dataset_corretto.df[j,i] = dataset.df[j,i] - riskfree.df[j,1] 
  }
}
dataset_corretto.df**
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using `dput(your data)`

Comment: R is vectorized and its matrices are in column first order, try `dataset_corretto.df - riskfree.df[,1]`. No loops.